# How do I find the Laurent series expansion?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I want to find the order of the pole of $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{z}}$ at 0. But how can I expand this function at 0? Can I take the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+z}$  and plug in $\frac{1}{z}$ in the place of z? And how can one find the Laurent series expansion of a function in general? I mean since the function diverges toward infinity at poles, how can the Laurent series be "defined"?

Comment: The function $\sqrt{1+1/z}$ has branch points at $z=-1$ and $z=0$.  So, you can develop the Laurent series outside the unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right that to find the Laurent series expansion for $f(z)=\sqrt{1+\frac1z}$ about $0,$ we need only start with the Taylor series expansion of $g(z)=\sqrt{1+z}$ about $0,$ then note that $f(z)=g(1/z).$ In fact, this will show you that it isn't a pole, but rather an essential singularity.

As for how the Laurent series can be thought of as being defined, recall that a power series is defined wherever it converges. In this case, it converges at all values of $z$ such that $|z|>1.$

Comment: The Taylor series of $g$ around $z = 0$ converges for $|z| < 1$, so the corresponding Laurent series of $f$ converges for $|z| > 1$, not for all non-zero $z$. $f$ does not have a Laurent series expansion on $0 < |z| < r$, $z = 0$ is not an essential singularity of $f$.

Comment: @Maxim: Right you are! I was considering the completely wrong series.

Comment: To be clear, the new center of expansion $z = \infty$ is not an essential singularity of $f$ either.